# What are these half-size parking spaces in a supermarket lot?

Tags: uk, automobiles, road-signs

Please let me know what this highlighted parking space is for

[image: parkingpic]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, well-received as it may be, it's really not about *travel* as defined in https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @brhans presumably the people who passed their driving tests where that photo was taken knew or learned how local pavement marking works.  Visitors from another place might not.  We have lots of questions about rules of the road and similar things that aren't strictly about travel but are nonetheless of interest to travelers.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's two **motorcycle parking spaces**, somewhat confusingly embedded in markings of similar size that mean "don't park here".

Comment: which line shows "dont park here"?

Comment: @maneeshmurali the hatched areas  are meant to be avoided.  The way they're used doesn't fit the [Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/general-rules-techniques-and-advice-for-all-drivers-and-riders-103-to-158#rule130) but that's not surprising on private land.  Also not surprising is the motorbike spaces being unlabelled

Comment: @maneeshmurali The cross-hatch lines that make up most of that photos, with the exception of the motorcycle parks and the disabled parks (and obviously the road - although you probably also shouldn't park there!)

Comment: Interesting that the only way to enter the motorcycle/handicapped spaces is by crossing over the hatched area. You cannot enter them from the openings on the side near the store, since there are posts in the way.

Comment: I think those embedded markings do mean not only "do not park here" but "do not drive over here" (obiously except for parking at the designated spaces), as they delimit the lane.

Comment: @SJuan76 correct, but the solid lines also mean "don't drive over them except in an emergency"

Comment: Interesting to have motorcycle parking spaces in front of an Aldi - I don't know how they operate in the UK, but at least in the US, Aldi is famous for saving money by not providing grocery bags.  A small issue with a car, but a motorcycle's carrying space is much more limited.  Guess you just have to make more frequent trips and buy less stuff.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it seems in my city that buildings get "green points" for providing bicycle parking.  Most grocery stores provide bicycle parking.  Would Aldi get similar green points for motorcycle parking? Also what else would Aldi do with those small bits of land?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman "in the US, Aldi is famous for _saving money_ by not providing grocery bags." ... and _saving the planet_. In the UK, all supermarkets have stopped giving away plastic bags (by law), but they can be bought at the checkout (generally more robust / reusable ones), [including Aldi](https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/p-aldi-eco-loopcarrier-bag-1-bag/4088600252407). (I would have thought that someone grocery shopping on their motorcycle would already be prepared in how they would carry everything - not dependent on free grocery bags?)

Comment: @SJuan76 They could maybe use the box junction markings instead, but that would also be a little complicated... It's important that they have something reminding people to keep that area clear since a lot of accessible vehicles now have entry/exit from the rear and need enough room back there to extend a ramp/lift.

Comment: @MrWhite That wasn't a criticism, just an observation that it would be somewhat more inconvenient for motorcycles than for cars.

Comment: @MrWhite ahh, the good ol' days when we decided to "save the trees" by switching from paper bags to plastic...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: in the rest of the world, you're expected to go to the supermarket with the bags/baskets you intend to carry stuff home in. Aldi's method of providing an area where you can pack your bags is exactly how everyone in Europe has been doing it since at least the 1950s.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I wonder how easy it would be to carry those grocery bags on a motorcycle anyway, regardless of if you got them from the store, or brought them with you. I know that I can ride a bicycle for a short distance with a bag hanging from the handlebar, but it's... not optimal, to say the least. Using a backpack would be smarter.

Comment: @ikkachu Just use a BMW C1 ;-) It has an incredible loading capacity... I did a couple of moving with it.

Comment: @pacoverflow Presumably so that once the cars are parked, they aren't obstructed anywhere that a (for example) wheelchair user might need to access.